# display all option in select without click

Tags: html, css, select, frontend

guys i need your litle help i want to make select that show all option without to click select, i try add "multiple" but when i try in mobile display go wrong
[this is what i want in front-end to mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXYQF.png)

[but on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCna6.jpg)

[here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/iqbalchandra27/Leq4w09g/3/)

```
<style>
    select {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 14;
        cursor: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        outline: none;
        text-align: center;
        height: 90;
    }

    select option {
        margin-top: 10;
    }
</style>
<div class="select m-auto">
                <select id="standard-select" name="bahasa" multiple>
                    <option value="id">Bahasa Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="en">Inggris</option>
                    <option value="viet">Vietnamese</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: It seems working fine as you require in mobile screen!
Try another browser

Comment: Does it make sense to use a 'select multiple' as the user will only select one language? Maybe consider using a single select or maybe showing a list of links?

Comment: I suspect you will have to implement your own version of select because (at least on the IOS I am using) you cannot simulate a click event on the select and multiple and size do not work.

Answer (score 1):

do be aware that size or multiple is not respected by mobile devices, but it works fine on desktops

you can try - **overflow:auto;**

```css
 select {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 14;
        cursor: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        outline: none;
        text-align: center;
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="select m-auto">
                <select id="standard-select" name="bahasa" multiple>
                    <option value="id">Bahasa Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="en">Inggris</option>
                    <option value="viet">Vietnamese</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: This shows the text ‘0 items’ on my IOS device

Comment: i found to display all option wihout multiple, just put size in select 
<select id="standard-select" name="bahasa" size="3">
      <option selected value="id">Bahasa Indonesia</option>
      <option value="en">Inggris</option>
      <option value="viet">Vietnamese</option>
     </select>
it looks good in desktop but on mobile looks difrent but much better then use multiple

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically setting the label attribute would be enough for all **iOS** versions to display the control label. Turns out this depends on the **iOS** version.

you  not setting innerText on **iOS 7-9**, but **iOS 10 & up** requires innerText to be set for the label to display.

**required iOS 10 & up**

```
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    option.label = option.innerText = 'option label';
    option.value = '123';
```

**not required on iOS 7-9**

```
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.label = 'option label';
option.value = '123';
```